# What is the gradient of a distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open and $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ be the set of $C^\infty(\Omega)$-functions with compact support equipped with a locally convex topology.

> Let $\mathcal D(\Omega)'$ be the dual space of $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ and $p\in\mathcal D(\Omega)'$, i.e. $$p:\mathcal D(\Omega)\to\mathbb R$$ is linear and continuous. What is meant by the gradient $\nabla p$ of $p$ as it is been used in the paper [A Remark on the Characterization of the Gradient of a Distribution](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~wxm/paper/Wang_pressure.pdf)?

Comment: Almost certainly, it's the $d$-tuple of partial (distributional) derivatives.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the definition of a distributional derivative?

Comment: For a distribution $T$, we define $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_k}$ as the distribution $\varphi \mapsto -T\bigl[\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x_k}\bigr]$. That's the (partial) distributional derivative of $T$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I assume $k=1,\ldots,d$ and $\varphi\in\mathcal D(\Omega)$, right? Is your definition related to that in the Wikipedia article below? What is $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ in that article? Is it the scalar product in $L^2(\Omega)$? And why is their definition equivalent to yours?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Differentiation

Comment: Right, $1\leqslant k \leqslant d$, and $\varphi \in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$. It's the same thing, but using different notation. I used function application notation - $T[\varphi]$ - and the wikipedia article uses the natural pairing between a vector space and its dual, $\langle T,\varphi\rangle$ for the same thing. The dual pairing is in many ways similar to an inner product, but it's a different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the (vector) of distributions defined via
$$\nabla p : D(\Omega)^n \to \mathbb{R}, \quad \varphi \mapsto -\sum_{i=1}^np(\partial_{x_i} \varphi_i).$$

If $p$ is actually a funcion, the last sum is just
$$-\int_\Omega p(x) \, \operatorname{div}(\varphi)(x) \, \mathrm{d}x,$$
and if $p$ is (weakly) differentiable, you have
$$-\int_\Omega p(x) \, \operatorname{div}(\varphi)(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega \nabla p(x) \cdot \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: $n$ should be $d$, right?

Comment: 1. I don't know what you mean by "if $p$ is actually a function". What should it be else? $$-$$ 2. How do you define the (weak) differentiability of $p$? $$-$$ 3. Is this somehow related to the so-called Gâteaux derivative?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : once you showed that a distribution $T$ (a continuous and linear function $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$) can always be represented as $T(\varphi) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x) \varphi(x) dx$ where the $f_n \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, it becomes easy to define $[\frac{d}{dx_i} T] (\varphi) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} \frac{d f_n(x)}{dx_i}  \varphi(x) dx = - \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n(x) \frac{d}{dx_i} \varphi(x) dx = - T(\frac{d}{dx_i} \varphi)$

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, as usual $n = d$ ;)

Comment: @0xbadf00d: 1. You wrote that $p$ is a distribution. This is not a function. 2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative 3. No.

Comment: @gerw Are you sure about your definition of $\nabla p$? Since $\varphi$ is a mapping $\Omega\to\mathbb R^d$, what do you mean by $\partial x_i\varphi$? Maybe you've intended to write $\partial x_i\varphi_i$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected it.

Comment: @gerw You're welcome. I need to thank for your help

Comment: @gerw Sorry for necroing this old post, did I get you right, that if $p\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d)'$, then $\nabla p\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)'$ is defined via $$\nabla p(\phi)=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(\phi)\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in\mathcal D(\phi,\phi)?$$ This looks more like the "divergence" of $\nabla p$ (i.e. the "Laplacian").

Comment: No, you cannot use $\partial p / \partial x_i$ to define $\nabla p$, this would be a circular definition. And note that $\phi$ is vector-valued and I used $\phi_i$ in the definition.